# Android studio best layout foundation for responsive design?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a responsive design for my app so that I won't have to create multiple layout files for each activity or fragment (large-layout, -xlarge etc)

So far I've found that the support percent relative layout works best since it will look pretty much the same on all screen sizes, I just have to change the text size. I'm looking for something like this.

The docs says "build a responsive design using constraints", which I tried but it still uses DP for margins etc so it would still look really different on different screens. So in this case, why would for example constraint layout be good for a responsive design?

Comment: I reccommend you to have a look to this. Also *dp* is the best unit since it adapts to the screen without pixel dependency. Building a Responsive UI: https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-responsive-ui-in-android-7dc7e4efcbb3#.z0x33byvz

Answer (score 0):

`dp` are density independent. Even in a responsive application, you don't want your margins to blow up on huge screens. It's totally correct for your margin between two elements to stay at 20dp instead of growing linearily like the constrained buttons.

Comment: But if I would set an image view to 200 dp because that would be 50% of the screen on a normal size screen, and then in my xlarge layout I also set it to 200dp, then this wouldn't be 50% of the screen, right?

Comment: You can use `layout:weight="50"` and another view with the same weight. Then set `layout:width="0dp"` to create a 50% width View.